# Strange 9 Patch Drawing

Tags: android

I have a 9 patch image that looks like so

[image]

Basically we are trying to imitate the android textfield look. However this is drawing the black line which should be used for resizing. The background of the image is transparent, the only color is the line at the bottom. Is this a problem?

The file is named like this

filename.9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing left expand indicator, use this:
[image]  You should use some tool like [this](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to generate backgrounds for your `View`s.

Comment: nice link, thats helped me out!